# Password Protected HTML Data in QlikView

Tags: html, password-protection, qlikview

I am looking to grab data from an HTML table using the URL to define the data range.

The problem is that the site is password protected.  How do I send a userid/password to then grab the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should into some kind of proxy. This is because Qlikview can't handle cookies (except for in extensions on Qlikview 10 but that's not the point) while loading.

I created a php script on my own webserver which basically is a proxy written in php using cURL.

I then do something like this in Qlikview (half pseudo code):
let usr = myusername;
let pwd = mypassword;
let dataURL = urlwheretofetchdatafrom;
let loginURL = urltotheloginwindow;

table:
LOAD

FROM
http://mywebsite.com/myproxy.php?user=$(user)&password=$(pwd)... and so on

The script then uses my parameters to log me in and then sends a request to the dataURL and fetches the data. The qlikview loading script will then read the data from my website instead.

Down sides? 
This is not applicable for large quantities of data. It is also not possible to send password and username encrypted.

I might release some scripts for this in the future but as of now it's only in the testing phase.

/Jonas

Comment: It turns out it's just going to be easier to write a script in another language to grab the data.  It's a shame QlikView can't do this anymore.  I thought it used to be able to.